# Generate JQuery reference by generated HTML on event fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a web application I'm working on.  One facet of it supports the sending of messages.  Recently I've decided the user needs the ability to send files in their message.

TMI probably, but... I have a hidden input type=file, when the user clicks the image icon I fire trigger.  The user gets local file browser dialog, once a file is selected, I pass the file data via ajax, store the file and generate a link in a content editable div.  This is all working fine.

Here's the rub:
My anchor generated has title='' and then in JQuery I want to say:

```
$('id').tooltip({content: '<img src="" />'})
```

I'd like to have it work so when the user hovers over the anchor, a thumbnail of the uploaded image is displayed, but I am not sure how to 'put' the generated jquery out for use in my script.  That seems silly, but I just can't get my head around it.

Here's some code:

Once local file browse dialog is closed I catch event/grab data like so:

```
$('#file').on('change', function() {
            file_upload = $(this)[0].files[0];
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('function', 'file_upload');
            data.append('file_upload', file_upload);
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax_send_message.php',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {
                            if (data) {
                                    alert(data);
                            }
                    }
            });     
            var image_path = "path/to/file/<?=$member_id?>/"+file_upload.name;
            var image = "<a id='"+file_upload.name+"' href='"+image_path+"' title=''>Edit this text</a>";
            var body = $('#msg_body').html();
            body += image;
            $('#msg_body').html(body);
            $( "#"+file_upload.name+"" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="'+image_path+'" />' });
    });
```

Specifically, I'm not sure how to get this puppy out in the wild or tie it to something

```
$( "#"+file_upload.name+"" ).tooltip({ content: '<img src="'+image_path+'" />' });
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so here is the solution I came up with that worked for me.

First, I adjusted the original code I posted to look a little cleaner on the front end.  Rather handle all the path stuff in php.

```
$('#file').on('change', function() {
            file_upload = $(this)[0].files[0];
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('function', 'file_upload');
            data.append('file_upload', file_upload);
            data.append('msg_body', $('#msg_body').html());
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax_send_message.php',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {
                            if (data) {
                                    $('#msg_body').html(data);
                            }
                    }
            });     
    });
```

so in php I'm building html like so:

```
  $anchor_builder = "<a id='{$no_spaces}' href='{$image_path}'>
                     Edit this text
                     </a>";

  $msg_body .= "&nbsp;".$anchor_builder;
```

And then once again in JQuery, I added a tooltip function like so:

```
$(function() {
            $( document ).tooltip({
                    items: 'a, img, [title]',
                    tooltipClass: 'tooltip_font_size',
                    show: {
                            delay: 2000
                    },
                    content: function() {
                            var element = $( this );
                            if ( element.is( 'a' ) ) {
                                    var path = element.attr('href')
                                    return '<img src="'+path+'" />'
                            }
                            if ( element.is( '[title]' ) ) {
                                    return element.attr( 'title' );
                            }
                    }
            });
});
```

And now I'm 100% more worky.  Just need to work out width and height I'd like.